# Does dynamic_cast really work for multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I wanted to see if it's possible to create "interfaces", inherit them, and then check at runtime if any random class implements that interface. This is what I have:

```
struct GameObject {
    int x,y;
    std::string name;

    virtual void blah() { };
};

struct Airholder {
   int oxygen;
   int nitrogen;
};

struct Turf : public GameObject, public Airholder {
   Turf() : GameObject() {
      name = "Turf";
   }

   void blah() { };
};

void remove_air(GameObject* o) {
   Airholder* a = dynamic_cast<Airholder*>(o);
   if(!a) return;
   a->oxygen   = 0;
   a->nitrogen = 0;
};
```

Now, it works. The documentation says that it works, the test example works.. But also, it didn't compile until I added a virtual method to GameObject. The thing is, I really don't know if the feature is intended to be used like that. What made me wonder there is the fact that I have to declare a virtual function for the class I'm checking. But obviously, there is none, the class I'm checking itself has no virtual functions, in fact my whole code has nothing to do with virtual functions, it's an entirely different approach.

So, I guess my question is: If what I'm doing really works, why do I need a virtual function to give my class a vtable? Why can't I declare the class a "runtime type" or something without virtual functions?

Comment: I understand that this may be more of a learning exercise for you, but you can create an interface that has only pure virtual functions and go from there.

Comment: Which documentation said it works without a virtual function? And why do you say the test example worked if you couldn't even compile it?

Comment: @keith.layne: Even if Airholder had virtual functions, I still wouldn't be able to perform the checks. I think you're not understanding the problem.

Comment: @cib I *think* I understand.  My point is that this is a convoluted solution.  I know a little about dynamic_cast and RTTI and all that stuff, but have always stayed away from it because it seemed like not the best approach to my problems.  Maybe I was thrown off by your example being simpler than what you're really working on.  My real point is to prefer static type checks and polymorphism over any runtime stuff.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[EDIT] According to the comments (people way smarter than me) my answer is completely wrong.  However, make your destructors virtual anyway. [/EDIT]

In C++, I consider upcasting to a base type is only safe if the destructor is virtual. Technically it's safe, but in reality, you almost always want a virtual destructor.  For instance:

```
class Base {
   int thingy;
};
class Derived : Base{
   int *array;
   Derived() {array = new int[100];}
   ~Derived() {delete [] array;}
};
int main() {
    std::auto_ptr<Base> obj(dynamic_cast<Base*>(new Derived));
}
```

In this example, when obj goes out of scope, the auto_ptr automatically calls the Base's destructor, *but does not call the Derived deconstructor* because the type is a Base, not a Derived.  [Edit: corrections] This causes Undefined behaviour (at the very best, it causes a memory leak).  I haven't any idea why C++ doesn't require a virtual destructor to compile down casts, it really should.

Comment: The destructor does not have to be virtual to enable downcasting. It's a good idea (a very good idea), but it is not essential. The destructor only needs to be virtual if an instance of a derived class will be deleted via a base class pointer. What is essential to enable a downcast via `dynamic_cast` is that some member function does have to be virtual. If there is none a compliant compiler will reject (must reject!) the cast as illegal.

Comment: "downcasting to a base type is only safe if the destructor is virtual" That's not true *per se*, this is completely fine: `struct b {}; struct d : b {} x; (b&)d;`. In fact, the only danger of not having a virtual destructor is that, as in your example, *delete's* through a base class are undefined.

Comment: Downcasting to a *base* type doesn't require polymorphism. The compiler knows the layouts of the classes involved, so it can find the base pointer from the derived pointer without any run-time assistance. The part that's unsafe in your example code is the *destruction* of the object, not the casting or any other ordinary use of the pointer.

Comment: @Rob wouldn't _downcasting_ to a _base_ type be _upcasting_?

Comment: I have no idea which way is which, @Seth. Mooing Duck cast from a derived to a base and called it downcasting, so I went with that. The casting in the question is neither down nor up.

Comment: @Rob if the cast in question is either the code in Mooing's example or cib's code, it's upcasting (casting from down the class inheritance hirarchy to up the hierarchy).

Comment: @Rob: Going toward a base class is called *upcasting*. *Downcasting* is going toward a derived class.

Comment: In any case, this answer is flat out **wrong**. A virtual destructor is not needed for either upcasting or downcasting. So, -1.

Comment: @Seth, Cib's code casts from one type (GameObject) to a completely unrelated class (AirHolder). As for which way is up and down, it rather depends on which way you draw the hierarchy, doesn't it? I'd be tempted to draw a *base* class at the bottom, but I'd draw a *super* class at the top. Yet they're the same things.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Ah, I see. I didn't think about just how necessary virtual functions are for polymorphism. While it may not always be necessary to use a virtual destructor, in most cases it won't hurt, and it looks much better than making a function up.

Comment: It does not cause a memory leak. It causes Undefined Behaviour. This answer is wrong.

Comment: While this answer is wrong, it contains a valid explanation. I don't think the standard would be the way it is, if it weren't possible/sensible to declare the destructor virtual.

Comment: @cib: There is nothing about the destructor in the rationale. You can use `dynamic_cast` perfectly legitimately without a virtual destructor.

Comment: @DeadMG: But it's the best thing for me to do when I want to make my class polymorphic and have no other virtual functions. I wasn't asking about the standard(though it's good to know my compiler conforms to it), I was more interested in the reasoning behind it.

Comment: I considered virtual destructors a requirement for _upcasting_ (Which I always thought was downcasting.  Odd wording that.).  I didn't really think it was allowed to NOT use virtual constructors.  (If they're required, question became moot)  Also didn't realize that failing to have a virtual constructor would be UB vs a leak.  I'll stick to areas I know more about methinks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'll go with this answer since while it doesn't entirely answer my question, at least it solves my problem. :)

Answer (score 6):

§ 5.2.7 of the standard says:

1. The result of the expression dynamic_cast(v) is the result of converting the expression v to type
   T. T shall be a pointer or reference to a complete class type, or “pointer to cv void”. Types shall not be
   defined in a dynamic_cast. The dynamic_cast operator shall not cast away constness (5.2.11).
2. If T is a pointer type, v shall be an rvalue of a pointer to complete class type, and the result is an rvalue of
   type T. If T is a reference type, v shall be an lvalue of a complete class type, and the result is an lvalue of
   the type referred to by T.
3. If the type of v is the same as the required result type (which, for convenience, will be called R in this
   description), or it is the same as R except that the class object type in R is more cv-qualified than the class
   object type in v, the result is v (converted if necessary).
4. If the value of v is a null pointer value in the pointer case, the result is the null pointer value of type R.
5. If T is “pointer to cv1 B” and v has type “pointer to cv2 D” such that B is a base class of D, the result is a
   pointer to the unique B sub-object of the D object pointed to by v. Similarly, if T is “reference to cv1 B”
   and v has type “cv2 D” such that B is a base class of D, the result is an lvalue for the unique60) B sub-object
   of the D object referred to by v. In both the pointer and reference cases, cv1 shall be the same cvqualification
   as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv2, and B shall be an accessible unambiguous base class
   of D. [Example:

   struct B {};
   struct D : B {};
   void foo(D* dp)
   {
        B* bp = dynamic_cast(dp); // equivalent to B* bp = dp;
   }
   —end example]
6. **Otherwise, v shall be a pointer to or an lvalue of a polymorphic type (10.3).**

And **to make a type polymorphic, it needs a virtual function**, as per § 10.3:

> Virtual functions support dynamic binding and object-oriented programming. A class that declares or
>   inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class.

So the reason why is "because the standard says so." That doesn't really tell you *why* the standard says so though, but the other answers cover that well I think.

Comment: However, I did not ask "why doesn't my compiler let me dynamic_cast a non-polymorphic class". My question was "If situations like this exist, why can't you declare a polymorphic class without virtual functions?"

Comment: @cib that's just the design of the language. Why? Because they decided to make it that way.

Comment: Heheh, yeah. Sorry, I probably am asking too much of the language designers. In either case, I thought it was so bad that you'd have to define a useless virtual function like "virtual void blub()" in a situation like this, and that's what made me think a language like C++ couldn't have such a flaw. And it doesn't, since you can just make the destructor virtual, which will look much better.

Comment: @cib yeah, especially since you should do that anyways. So it's almost like it makes you do something you should already be doing to get the functionality you're talking about. GL.

Answer (score 2):

> So, I guess my question is: If what I'm doing really works, why do I need a virtual function to give my class a vtable? Why can't I declare the class a "runtime type" or something without virtual functions?

The presence of a virtual function is what makes a class polymorphic in C++. `dynamic_cast<>` only works with polymorphic classes. (The compiler will reject a dynamic cast on a non-polymorphic object.)

Polymorphism has a cost, both in time and in space (memory). Calls to virtual functions are now indirect, typically implemented in terms of a virtual table. In some critical places, those costs are simply unacceptable.  So the language provides means of avoiding these costs.

Similar concepts exist elsewhere in the language. The underlying principle is that if you don't want to use some high-falutin' feature you shouldn't have to pay for the fact the some people do want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need at least one virtual function to make a class polymorphic. Why this matters is that dynamic_cast itself is a polymorphic operation! Given a base class pointer, it returns different results based on the actual object it is called on.

C++ has a "don't pay for what you don't need" philosophy, thus the vtable (or whatever mechanism the compiler uses) is not provided unless there's a need as determined by the presence of a virtual function. Evidently the designers of C++ thought this was a reasonable requirement for the proper operation of dynamic_cast or they would have provided a way to generate a vtable without it.

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast` requires the type to be polymorphic, and without any virtual methods (or at least a virtual destructor) a type is not (run-time) polymorphic. Simple inheritance is not enough. The run-time type information used by `dynamic_cast` is stored alongside the vtable if remember correctly.

Comment: "`dynamic_cast` requires the type to be polymorphic": Only for downcasting. `dynamic_cast<parent_class*>(derived_class_pointer)` works fine. RTTI is not needed for upcasting; the code for such a cast is known at compile time. See Seth's answer; he quoted chapter and verse (at least in part). The semantics of `dynamic_cast` doesn't require polymorphic classes until paragraph 6.

Answer (score -1):

There are two main reasons. The first is that there's just no use case for it. The point of inheritance is virtual functions. If you're not using virtual functions, don't use inheritance.

The second is that it's very complex to actually implement `dynamic_cast` that works without virtual functions due to the C++ compilation model. The only way to realistically implement `dynamic_cast` is to operate on the virtual table- a binary blob of data is typeless. You could define a class and then only `dynamic_cast` it in one TU- now one TU thinks the class has a vtable and one doesn't. That would be instant bad. Allowing `dynamic_cast` on classes that do not already have virtual functions would be, well, `export`, which means "Exceedingly difficult to implement".

Comment: I think your first point is either wrong or too ideological for me to care. I gave a very practical example of why you could want to make runtime checks on a class that has no virtual functions, and it could look exactly like that in my actual project. The fact I *probably* want virtual functions in a polymorphic class doesn't mean I always want them.

Comment: @cib: That's what a `boost::optional` is for. There are plenty of other ways to design optional data members than inheritance. However, the second point is much more important than the first- that it would be fundamentally impossible.

Comment: "The point of inheritance is virtual functions. If you're not using virtual functions, don't use inheritance." I disagree with this. When working with templates, there are lots of use cases where you want inheritance with no virtual at all, e.g. CRTP and static hierarchies